# ajax star rating control not updating

Tags: asp.net

i am using ajax based star rating control... i have created a usercontrol for it... on my page i have placed the usercontrol... their is strange behaviour... on rating_changedd event i set the readonly to true and update the database... but after postback when page reload it still allow me to update the rating...

how can i make the star rating control readonly on postback?

Comment: There are many star rating controls, witch one you use ?

Comment: @Aristos I think this one http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/rating/rating.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple example and it looks like you will have to explicitly state `AutoPostBack="true"` and after that if you set `ReadOnly` on `Changed` event, it persists across postbacks.